# How to order the rsync copy of files?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, rsync

Is it possible to order file copy order for the rsync of a batch of N files?

For example,

if I have 5 files within a batch, I want to rsync them ordered by filename. Given the following files:

```
A1
C5
A2
B1
B4
```

Then the rsync order would be:

```
A1 (arrives first on remote_server)
A2
B1
B4
C5 (arrives last on remote server)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: From the rsync manual page it says that `rsync always sorts the specified filenames into its internal transfer list`, did you observe that the files are not transferred in order (add a `-n` option for dry run)?

Comment: rsync appears to sort on filename only in testing, but hoped to understand the variables surrounding this internal transfer list, and if there was a way to guarantee transfer order

Answer (score -3):

```
rsync A1 A2 B1 B4 C5 remote:/path/
```

Comment: Is this scalable? For example, 400 files with longer names?

Comment: It depends on your shell's capabilties.